# How can I change the Chrome Developers Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: windows, google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been using the old VS6 keyboard shorcuts for 20 years. I'd like to change Chrome to use the same *shortcuts* for debugging (Step Into, Over, etc.)

I can see the *shortcuts* but not change them, at:
In the Developer IDE, upper right corner, column of the 3 dots: Click that, choose Shortcuts from the drop down menu.
Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You'll have to use an external utility to remap the keys. Or patch Chrome's resources.pak that contains the javascript code for devtools.

Comment: The bindings are stored in [json format](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/sources/module.json?q=\WF8\b+-file:test+-file:/debug+file:devtools&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=30). Writing a patcher shouldn't be too hard (resources.pak structure is documented or at least there are packers/unpackers in python). And you can even write a file-watcher to autoprocess the newly created directory of the updated Chrome.